# О слове "только"

Tags: части-речи

Какой частью речи является слово "только" в предложениях:

- "Возьми только трёхкопеечную монету." (на столе перед ребёнком лежат одно-, двух- и трёхкопеечная монеты),
- "Дай мне только ложку." (на столе перед ребёнком лежат ложка, вилка и нож),
- "Принеси мне только кубик." (на столе перед ребёнком лежат шарик, кубик и кольцо)?

Answer (score 3):

Уважаемый Галактион! Можно я отвечу? Это частица со значением  "единственно, исключительно", имеющая местоименное происхождение.

ДИАЛОГ

- А с/ко/ли/ко предметов надо взять/дать/принести?
- А с/то/ли/ко, с/ко/ли/ко тебе сказали: то/ли/ко один (исключительный, единственный, названный).

Comment: Большое спасибо.